# Function doesn't return reversed array

Tags: c#, arrays, function, return

As newbie to C# I try to reverse an array with a method. But it returns not the reversed array. I tried for hours but still don't get it what I am doing wrong. The whole thing is a lesson from "The C# Players guide - 2nd edition" book I have bought. Unfortunately the solutions of the lessons are not included in the book. The `Main` method ist predefined and should be used like you can see.

If I do the output within the `for` loop it is `54321` and this would be fine. But the correct output should come from the `PrintNumbers` method. And there is the problem because the output `12345` is not reversed

Here is the code, please tell me if you see something bad.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] numbers = GenerateNumbers();
        Reverse(numbers);
        PrintNumbers(numbers);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    //Generate the array and return the numbers
    static int[] GenerateNumbers()
    {
        int[] temp;
        temp = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        return temp;
    }

    //Reverse the numbers in the array
    static int[] Reverse(int[] numbersToSwap)
    {
        //Write array length in value to decrement later
        int numbersLenghtMax = numbersToSwap.Length;
        //Minus 1 because an array starts with 0
        numbersLenghtMax--;

        //Create a temp value to store last value of array
        int[] temp = new int[numbersToSwap.Length];

        for (int index = 0; index < numbersToSwap.Length; index++)
        {
            //Store values reversed in the temp value
            temp[index] = numbersToSwap[numbersLenghtMax];
            numbersLenghtMax--;

            //This output is correct
            Console.Write(temp[index]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        //The returned array is not reversed
        return temp;

    }

    //Print out the numbers
    static void PrintNumbers(int[] numbers)
    {
        foreach (int number in numbers)
            Console.Write(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not using the return value of the `Reverse` method. The argument `numbers/numbersToSwap` is not modified.

Comment: You could use ``System.Linq`` or ``Array.Reverse()`` to reverse your array

Comment: Thanks, I have read about the `Array.Reverse()` but the lesson is to do it without. Because it is about learning how functions work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Reverse` method returns an `int[]` (the result of reversing the array), but you are not using such return value.

Use it like this:

```
int[] numbers = GenerateNumbers();
numbers = Reverse(numbers); //Assign the return value to the numbers variable
PrintNumbers(numbers);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem. I thought the function will always return back to the value `numbers`.

Answer (score 4):

It's returning the value:

```
static int[] Reverse(int[] numbersToSwap)
{
    // other code

   return temp;
}
```

You're just not doing anything with the returned value:

```
Reverse(numbers);
```

You have to *assign* the returned value to something:

```
numbers = Reverse(numbers);
```

Comment: I am so blind. Thanks that make sense. I thought the return `temp` will be renamed to the arguments `numbers` and the main method don't know the `temp` value.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is returning the reversed array, however you are not using it.

The function returns a new variable (`temp`) that contains your reversed array, you need to store this return value somewhere.

```
int[] numbers = GenerateNumbers();
Reverse(numbers);  // You pass in the numbers array & are returned a reversed version of it
PrintNumbers(numbers); // You print the original unmodified numbers array
```

Your `Reverse` function does not modify the numbers array at all. Instead it returns a new variable which represents what was stored in `temp` at the end of the function.

You would want to update your code to use the return value, like this:

```
int[] numbers = GenerateNumbers();
numbers = Reverse(numbers);
PrintNumbers(numbers);
```

Comment: So the predefined main code is not correct? Or can I store the value in the  `Reverse` function to the `numbers` array?

Comment: You can store the return value of the Reverse function in the numbers array. Just keep in mind that by doing so you will lose the original values and have no way to recover them.

Answer (score -1):

Declare and set array element values:

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
```

Reverse elements of array:

```
Array.Reverse(array);
```

See:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The question is not how to reverse an array, but why the specific code isn't working.

Comment: and my response says without saying it, the code is already written for this functionality. why rebuild what is already inherent in C#. the whole point of the 13 years of evolution of the .NET Framwork is to provide functionality that does not need to be rebuilt over and over again.

Comment: and to punctuate my comment, the accepted answer is in other words, exactly what I posted.

Comment: The point is that the OP is learning.  When learning you often do things that there are already libraries for.  Also the accepted answer does not use `Array.Reverse`, it shows the OP that they need to assign the results of their `Reverse` method to the original variable.